# SQL - Using an exclusion List from another table with a wild card

Tags: sql, wildcard

I have created a table with a number of business exclusion names within it for the purpose of when I receive a weekly data file I want to run the business names against the exclusion list which I will then flag as being excluded. I can achieve this if it was the exact name I was wanting to exclude, but I want to run a wildcard on each business exclusion name against my new data.

For example:
I have in my exclusion table a business exclusion name that is "Marks and Spencers" but I have in my new data file an account called "Marks and Spencers Manchester" which I want to exclude so a like for like wouldn't match so I would want to do something possibly using the Like function and in this example use something like "  Where ExclusionName like "Marks and Spencer%"   "
I can obviously achieve using the above logic but I want to go through all the data in the new file iterating through the exclusion list flagging if the account is to be excluded or not.

Would this have to achieved using a cursor? and how efficient would that be with a larger data file and a reasonably large exclusion list?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks

DC

Comment: Can you import your data into a table?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to expand your exclusions table so that it's a "what to do" table.  Each record should include, at the very least, a business name and a "what to do field".  The values would indicate whether you should include or exclude records from your weekly imports.

When you get your weekly imports, put all records into a staging table.  Then run a report showing all names which are not in the "what to do" table.  Make a decision on each record and add it to the table with the appropriate values.  Then carry on with whatever you have to do with the weekly import.

This might appear to be tedious, but you'll get better results.  Using the Marks and Spencers example, in addition to the city at the end part, you might get some records with apostrophe's, spelling mistakes, city at the start, and so on and so forth.